# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed - Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to build an APK using assembleDebug command of gradle but I'm currently facing this error:

```
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed`
```

with the following output:

```
  * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed   Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-0.9.6.0.aar\18f1091c245c93f2961ec83a1230d434\res\anim\popup_exit.xml: error: file not found.
     Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e73f7e9c03a39a7518e973bff44c7fef\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\HIRI App Android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-0.9.6.0.aar\18f1091c245c93f2961ec83a1230d434\res\anim\popup_exit.xml Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

> ```
>  buildscript {
>         ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
>
>         repositories {
>             google()
>             jcenter()
>         }
>         dependencies {
>             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>             classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
>             classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
>             classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
>             // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>             // in the individual module build.gradle files
>         }
>     }
>
>     allprojects {
>         repositories {
>             google()
>             jcenter()
>             maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>             maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
>
>         }
> ```

**The gradle version I'm using is 4.9**

I'm facing the same issue for two other projects as well.